# Conditional selection of columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a special case where I need to get the username and user image that is the "opposite" of the given user_id. What I mean is, if you have a user id of 10, and you want to get messages that are relevant to that user, then I want the username and user image that is the opposite of the user with user_id of 10. So if someone with user_id of 3 has sent a message to someone with user_id of 10, then I want that message to be selected, but I only want the username and user image of the user that does not have user_id 10, which is the user_id I am given.

I have 3 tables to work with:

The user table:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email        | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(40)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| geonameid    | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| birthdate    | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hash         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_id     | int(11) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| about        | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| verified     | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| notification | int(1)           | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| joined       | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastactivity | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ipv4         | int(11) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ipv6         | binary(16)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted      | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The image table:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| width     | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| height    | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| extension | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created   | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| deleted   | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the messages table:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| message      | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reply_to     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| from_id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| to_id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| active       | int(1)           | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| sent         | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| viewed       | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| from_deleted | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| to_deleted   | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| deleted      | int(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Right now I have this query:

```
    SELECT
        message.id,
        message.message,
        message.reply_to AS replyTo,
        message.from_id AS fromId,
        message.to_id AS toId,
        message.sent,
        message.viewed,
        fromuser.username as fromUsername,
        touser.username as toUsername,
        CONCAT('".UPLOAD_URL."/img/', SUBSTR(image.name, 1, 2), '/', SUBSTR(image.name, 3, 2), '/', SUBSTR(image.name, 5, 2), '/', image.name, '-50x50', '.' ,image.extension) AS thumbnail50x50
    FROM
        message AS message
    INNER JOIN user AS fromuser
        ON message.from_id = fromuser.id
    INNER JOIN user AS touser
        ON message.to_id = touser.id
    INNER JOIN image AS image
        ON image.id = fromuser.image_id
    WHERE
        (message.from_id = :user_id OR message.to_id = :user_id) AND
        message.active = 1 AND
        message.deleted = 0
    ORDER BY message.sent DESC;
```

Instead of selecting fromuser.username and selecting touser.username
and selecting the image of the user that has sent the message,
I would like to select something like: oppositeuser.username, and the image.name of the opposite user as done in the query above. The special case here is that I need the username and user image of the opposite user of the given user_id, and not both the fromuser and touser.

Comment: Am I getting this right, if `message.from_id = :user_id` matches you want the image and the name of the receiving user and if `message.to_id = :user_id` matches you want the image and the name of the sending user?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I ment

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using IF().

```
SELECT
    message.id,
    message.message,
    message.reply_to AS replyTo,
    message.from_id AS fromId,
    message.to_id AS toId,
    message.sent,
    message.viewed,
    IF(message.from_id = :user_id, touser.username, fromuser.username) as oppositeName,
    IF(message.from_id = :user_id, 
        CONCAT('".UPLOAD_URL."/img/', SUBSTR(toimage.name, 1, 2), '/', SUBSTR(toimage.name, 3, 2), '/', SUBSTR(toimage.name, 5, 2), '/', toimage.name, '-50x50', '.' ,toimage.extension), 
        CONCAT('".UPLOAD_URL."/img/', SUBSTR(fromimage.name, 1, 2), '/', SUBSTR(fromimage.name, 3, 2), '/', SUBSTR(fromimage.name, 5, 2), '/', fromimage.name, '-50x50', '.' ,fromimage.extension) 
        ) AS thumbnail50x50
FROM
    message AS message
INNER JOIN user AS fromuser
    ON message.from_id = fromuser.id
INNER JOIN user AS touser
    ON message.to_id = touser.id
INNER JOIN image AS fromimage
    ON fromimage.id = fromuser.image_id
INNER JOIN image AS toimage
    ON toimage.id = touser.image_id
WHERE
    (message.from_id = :user_id OR message.to_id = :user_id) AND
    message.active = 1 AND
    message.deleted = 0
ORDER BY message.sent DESC;
```

Comment: I am getting, #1054 - Unknown column 'image.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I failed to rename all occurences of image to fromimage or toimage.

Comment: It works! Thank you. By the way do you think I should denormalize some of the tables because of all the joins?

Comment: I don't think that denormalizing is a good idea. If you want to reduce the number of joins there might be an alternative aproach using `UNION` - you could use two different query for `message.from_id = :user_id` and `message.to_id = :user_id`, combine the results with `UNION` and sort them afterwards. This would require more queries but may be faster if you have a lot of users and messages.